# std::move for "in-place operation"

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

This is probably pretty similar to other questions; I looked around a bit but I don't know what I'm talking about well enough to be sure.

I'm writing a function that "should" be in-place, but which is implemented by a BLAS call. The BLAS call is not in-place so I need to make a temporary. Thus:

```
void InPlace(ArrayClass& U, const TransformMatrix* M){
    ArrayClass U_temp; 
    CallBLASdgemm(U, M, U_temp);   //Now U_temp contains the correct output.
    U = std::move(U_temp);
}
```

Is this a valid use of `std::move`, or am I somehow breaking "copy elision" (or is it bad for some other reason)?

Edit: the signature of CallBLASDgemm was requested; it is

```
CallBLASdgemm(const ArrayClass& U, const TransformMatrix* M, 
              ArrayClass& V);
```

Comment: it's fine. but if `ArrayClass` doesn't support move assignment, you would still copy it anyway.

Comment: what is the signature of `CallBLASdgemm `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No copies are performed with or without copy elision in this case so that's already out of the question. Because `U_temp` is an lvalue the compiler has to call the copy constructor if you'd do :

```
U = U_temp;
```

However, you know that `U_temp` won't be used anymore and thus moving away its values is completely safe and can possibly be faster (that is, if `ArrayClass` implements a move assignment constructor). Using `std::move` here is fine and even encouraged.

Comment: @TobySpeight I can never seem to get that one right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a valid use case.  If you have a named temporary (lvalue) the only way to move it into `U` is to use `std::move` to cast it to a rvalue.

I think what you are worried about is when people do `return std::move(object);`.  That is a pessimization as that copy of object into the return value can be elided in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid.  However, what I'd do is this:

```
ArrayClass myCallBLASdgemm(const ArrayClass& U, const TransformMatrix* M) {
  ArrayClass tmp;
  CallBLASdgemm(U, M, tmp);
  return tmp; // elided move
}
void InPlace(ArrayClass& U, const TransformMatrix* M){
  U = myCallBLASdgemm(U, M);
}
```

which runs the same code, but does it without a temporary being visible in the outer scope.

In fact, `myCallBLASdgemm` is so clean you can probably eliminate `InPlace` and just call `myClassBLASdgemm` where you need it.